# Zbar scanner for android

Tags: android, android-intent, zbar-sdk

I am integrating the Zbar scanner into my android application by following this project - https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner. I am looking to place an image over the scanner when the camera appears. I know how to do this in iOS by just adding a subview to the scanner -

```
    UIImageView * image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scan.png"];
    image2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [reader.view addSubview:image2];
```

Is there a way to do this for android?

Comment: I just found a way to do that and shared:

[Customize Camera View for Android using zbar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19808502/2068509